# Several events and memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

I create several elements with attached events and delete them with "innerHTML = ''". The elements are out, but what about the events ? Are they erased as well ?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var container = document.createElement ("div");
            container.style.marginTop = "20px";

        var erase = document.createElement ("input");
            erase.setAttribute ("type", "button");
            erase.value = "Erase inputs";

        var insert = document.createElement ("input");
            insert.setAttribute ("type", "button");
            insert.value = "Insert inputs";

        document.body.appendChild (insert);
        document.body.appendChild (erase);
        document.body.appendChild (container);

        erase.onclick = function () {
            if (container.innerHTML !== "") {
                container.innerHTML = "";

                alert ("innerHTML = \"\". What about the events ?")
            }
        }

        insert.onclick = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
                var input = document.createElement ("input");
                    input.setAttribute ("type", "button");
                    input.value = "Click Me !";

                input.onclick = function () {
                    alert ("STOP ! Hammer time :)")
                }

                container.appendChild (input);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Possible memory leak ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - to be safe, set your "onclick" attributes to null before you blow away the contents.

```
    erase.onclick = function () {
        if (container.innerHTML !== "") {
            var inps = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var inpi = 0; inpi < inps.length; ++inpi)
              inps[i].onclick = null; // also "onchange", "onblur", anything else

            container.innerHTML = "";

            alert ("innerHTML = \"\". What about the events ?")
        }
    }
```

The DOM node garbage collector in Internet Explorer doesn't know what to do with JavaScript garbage, so it's lost. (It may well be the case that DOM nodes dangling off free JavaScript objects are similarly ignored; I can't recall exactly.)

Each one of those event handlers will have a reference to the closures formed by the outer "onload" handler and by the "onclick" handler of the "insert" control. They'll all be sharing a reference, so in this particular case I don't *think* it'd be that much memory. If, however, you set up each of those 1000 event handlers via *another* function, then there'd be that much more leakage.

I hate to say this, but one of the conveniences of using a framework is that a lot (**not all** but a lot) of this sort of thing is taken care of for you.

Comment: I believe that's mainly an IE6/7 issue. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @patrick dw I'm not sure how vulnerable IE8 is; I'd believe either case. In practical terms, I think we're stuck with IE7 for at least a little while longer, and for me anyway such distinctions are just academic. Also I didn't mention that using fancier methods of attaching event handlers (probably) also helps a lot too.

Comment: The reason I mention it is that it would seem that memory leaks using a library can be worse (if you venture outside the library's api) in that it would affect all browsers instead of being confined to only those where the native implementation is affected. I've been meaning to dig deeper into finding out which browsers are affected by such leaks. Only ones I'm certain of are IE6/7.

Comment: @patrick yes agreed - my personal feeling is that if you're going to build applications with a library, it's best to totally dive in and hand over all sorts of appropriate responsibilities to the library. Frameworks can't help you deal with problems you don't expose to them :-)

Comment: That's true. Still if you load an additional library which does its own 'remove', or you just forget, and use `innerHTML = 'whatever'`, you end up much worse off. Thinking specifically of jQuery (I don't know how the others work) where the only link between the element and the handlers (and all sorts of other data) is the expando property on the element, you'll now have a nice memory leak that is fully cross-browser compatible. ;o)